# Unwanted space after footnote mark

Tags: spacing, footnotes

I want to remove the small space after footnote mark (it especially visible before punctuation marks). MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Text\footnote{first}. Text\footnote{second} continues.
\end{document}
```

I've tested the negative kern, but the space is different depending on overall line space.

[image]

Comment: Is it really a space? `Text$^1$.` gives bare-eye identical result. Of course you are always free to use `\!` to manually *fix* it.

Comment: I think the space just looks so big b/c the 1 is small and hovers above the baseline. Notice the space between the `s` and the `.` at the end is also relatively big. I played around a bit and it would seem that the whitespace around a footnotemark (... I believe its called. I am talking about the ¹) is indeed slighly larger than between "normal" letters.

Comment: In publishing, it's traditional to place the footnote marker *after* the punctuation, at least if the punctuation is a period or comma.  That avoids unsightly spacing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton In “English typography”, yes, but [not in French typography](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8423/appel-de-note-de-bas-de-page-et-virgule), at least. :-)

Comment: @frougon -- Fair enough.  Different languages (and locations) do have different traditions.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @barbarabeeton in cyrillic typography we also place marker before punctuation (as in French).

Comment: @Symbol1 I've ended with `\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\scriptsize\@thefnmark}\!}}`

Answer (score 5):

That's exactly what `fnpct` is for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fnpct}
\setfnpct{punct-after}

\begin{document}

Text\footnote{first}. Text\footnote{second} continues.

\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fnpct}

\begin{document}

Text\footnote{first}. Text\footnote{second} continues.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The amount of shifting is customizable.